# IPhone - copyWithZone leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, constructor, copy, copywithzone

Testing my app on the device it returns a leak  whe i call the copy of a custom object ande i can't understand why.

this is the call:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (SinglePart *sp in [copyFrom partList]) {
    [arr addObject:[sp copy]];
}
self.partList = arr;
[arr release];
```

this is the method:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    SinglePart *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithSinglePart:self];
    [copy loadImage];
    return copy;
}
```

this is the method that is called by copyWithZone:

```
- (id)initWithSinglePart:(SinglePart *)copyFrom {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.imagePath = [copyFrom.imagePath copy];
        self.color = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:copyFrom.color.CGColor];
        self.hasOwnColor = copyFrom.hasOwnColor;
        self.blendingMode = copyFrom.blendingMode;
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copy` returns a new object with retain count 1.  Meaning you need to release the new object, which you are not doing.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (SinglePart *sp in [copyFrom partList]) {
    SingPart *theCopy = [sp copy];
    [arr addObject:theCopy];
    [theCopy release];
}
self.partList = arr;
[arr release];
```

Even your custom `copyWithZone:` method inits an object, but does not autorelease it, which is the expected behavior of a `copy` method.  Copy must be balanced just like a retain or init, meaning you must balance it with release at some point.

Lastly, your `initWithSinglePart:` method leaks the `imagePath` as well.  In this case if you declare the `imagePath` property as `copy` instead of `retain` then you don't need to do this manually at all.  Then you simply assign the value and let the property setter do it for you.

```
// Header
@property (copy) NSString *imagePath;

// Now this will do the copy for you
self.imagePath = copyFrom.imagePath;
```

Comment: Thanks really much... i really need to read a bit further about memory management. Can you suggest some link? :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 1):

Also, is the property `imagePath`  defined with `retain` or `copy` semantics?

If so you need to add an autorelease here:

```
self.imagePath = [[copyFrom.imagePath copy] autorelease];
```

because the default setter will retain/copy it too.

So, you either need to autorelease, or omit the "self." to bypass the default setter.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a copy of `sp` and then adding it to the array. The array then retains the object so your retain count is now 2.

In the end you release `arr`, thus making the retain count of it's items 1.

You should either add another release to the `sp` objects, or not use `copy`.

Try this:

```
self.partList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
for (SinglePart *sp in [copyFrom partList]) {
    [arr addObject:sp];
}
```